# How to Convert From one currency into another in Oracle query

Tags: oracle

I am selecting filial expenditures in US dollar for a particular date. But I need to convert it into Won currency for that date. Currencies`s value changes at any time according to US dollar. Currency history is in table of **V_CURRENCY**. I need to multiply dollar to that amount and show in Won. My query is below and giving an error. Error is **[22008][1861] ORA-01861**. Mismatch of rows.

```
with cte as (
    select t.filial_code,
           t.modified_by                      as emp_code,
           sum(t.sum_oper)                    as summa,
           to_char(t.oper_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as operation_date
    from OPERS t,
         DEP_OPERS d
    WHERE 
      And t.modified_by = 213
      And t.filial_code = '00116'
      And d.currency_code = 840
      And t.oper_date >= to_date('07.01.2020', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
      And t.oper_date < to_date('11.01.2020', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
    group by to_char(t.oper_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), t.filial_code, t.modified_by
) select cte.filial_code,cte.emp_code,cte.summa * (select equival from V_CURRENCY
    where date_activ = (select max(date_activ)
                            from V_CURRENCY
                         where date_activ <= cte.operation_date) and code = 840) as summa,cte.operation_date from cte;
```

From cte I am taking below result :

```
FILIAL_CODE | EMP_CODE | SUMMA | OPERATION_DATE
-----------------------------------------------
00116       | 213      | 40000 | 2020-01-14
00116       | 213      | 6000  | 2020-01-10
00116       | 213      | 2800  | 2020-01-06
```

My **V_CURRENCY** table is like below:

```
CODE   | DATE_ACTIV             | EQUIVAL|
--------------------------------
840    | 2020-01-13 00:00:00    | 576.97
840    | 2020-01-07 00:00:00    | 2008.54
840    | 2020-01-06 00:00:00    | 1941.91
840    | 2019-12-22 00:00:00    | 301.62
190    | 2020-01-13 00:00:00    | 1200.97
270    | 2020-01-13 00:00:00    | 2300.21
800    | 2019-12-22 00:00:00    | 100.62
```

I need to multiply equival from table **V_CURRENCY** in date **2020-01-13 00:00:00** to my cte result SUMMA for *OPERATION_DATE* **2020-01-14**, means that 4000 * 576.97, cause **OPERATION_DATE** is closest one to currency change date. But when *DATE_ACTIV* exists for date 2020-01-06 then 2800 * 1941.91. I only need curreny value whose code is 840.

My last result should look like :

```
FILIAL_CODE | EMP_CODE | SUMMA           | OPERATION_DATE
-----------------------------------------------
00116       | 213      | 40000 * 576.97  | 2020-01-14
00116       | 213      | 6000 *  2008.54 | 2020-01-10
00116       | 213      | 2800  * 1941.91 | 2020-01-06
```

Any response appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: no need to convert date value to string ( `to_char(t.oper_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` ) . And do not use old comma-seperated query syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `LEAD` analytic function to find the date the currency conversion is valid up until and then join the tables on the range between the start and end dates the currency is valid for:

```sql
SELECT y.filial_code,
       y.emp_code,
       y.summa * c.equival AS summa,
       y.operation_date
FROM   your_cte y
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT c.*,
                LEAD( DATE_ACTIV, 1, SYSDATE )
                  OVER ( PARTITION BY code ORDER BY date_activ )
                  AS DATE_FINISHED
         FROM   v_currency c
         WHERE  currency_code = 840
       ) c
       ON (   y.operation_date >= c.date_activ
          AND y.operation_date <  c.date_finished )
```

Outputs:

> ```
> FILIAL_CODE | EMP_CODE |    SUMMA | OPERATION_DATE
> :---------- | -------: | -------: | :-------------
> 00116       |      213 | 23078800 | 14-JAN-20     
> 00116       |      213 | 12051240 | 10-JAN-20     
> 00116       |      213 |  5437348 | 06-JAN-20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3e2bfcea297d60840fd063c133f89bb3)*

As an aside, your CTE doesn't need to convert dates to strings and can use date literals and a modern ANSI join (rather than legacy comma join):

```sql
with cte ( filial_code, emp_code, summa, operation_date ) as (
    SELECT t.filial_code,
           t.modified_by,
           sum(t.sum_oper),
           t.oper_date
    from   OPERS t
           CROSS JOIN
           DEP_OPERS d
    WHERE  t.modified_by   = 213
    AND    t.filial_code   = '00116'
    AND    d.currency_code = 840
    AND    t.oper_date     >= DATE '2020-01-07'
    AND    t.oper_date     <  DATE '2020-01-11'
    GROUP BY t.oper_date,
             t.filial_code,
             t.modified_by
)
...
```

and you don't even need the CTE:

```sql
SELECT t.filial_code,
       t.modified_by               AS emp_code,
       SUM(t.sum_oper * c.equival) AS summa,
       t.oper_date                 AS operation_date
FROM   OPERS t
       CROSS JOIN
       DEP_OPERS d
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT c.*,
                LEAD( DATE_ACTIV, 1, SYSDATE )
                  OVER ( PARTITION BY code ORDER BY date_activ )
                  AS DATE_FINISHED
         FROM   v_currency c
       ) c
       ON (   t.oper_date     >= c.date_activ
          AND t.oper_date     <  c.date_finished
          AND d.currency_code = c.currency_code )
WHERE  t.modified_by   = 213
AND    t.filial_code   = '00116'
AND    d.currency_code = 840
AND    t.oper_date     >= DATE '2020-01-07'
AND    t.oper_date     <  DATE '2020-01-11'
GROUP BY t.oper_date,
         t.filial_code,
         t.modified_by
```

Comment: It is giving an error. In v_currency  other currencies also saved maybe for that reason I updated v_currency  table. I need only currency with code  840

Comment: @Abdusoli "It is giving an error" is not a constructive statement. What error? Where? Have you tried debugging it? Can you create a fiddle which replicates the error? The data in your original edit did not have any other currency codes.

Comment: Updated to correlate on the currency code and fix a few aliases in the last query.

Comment: Sorry Bro I found my mistake. My mistake was  to_char(t.oper_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')